# why do I get syntax error for else statement in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I used the code below in python 3.9 and it runs with no problem at all but when I use it in 2.7 version it doesnt work I retyped the code 5 times and still doesnt work. it gives me syntax error for the else

Please help me with this

```
for row in range(7):
    for col in range(11):
        if ((col==0 or col==6 or col==10) or (row==3 and col==1))or((row==2) and (col==2 or col==8)) or (row==4 and col==2) or ((row==1) and (col==3 or col==7 or col==9)) or (row==5 and col==3) or ((row==0 or row==6) and (col==4)):
            print("*",end="")
else:
print(end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: 1. Indentation after else, 2. `print()` is syntax of Python3, in python2 its `print ""`, 3. If you want to use syntax of python3 in python2 use this import: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: I'm really curious why this has to run with Python 2. Python 2 reached end of life in the beginning of 2020 and that was announced over 10(!) years ago. So why is there still a need to run this code with Python 2?

Answer (score 2):

`print("something")` is the syntax of the python3.

in python2, it is `print "something"`.

---

Add the following code to the first line of the code, then you can use `print(...)` in python2.7:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax different between python2 and python3.
Not all python2 codes run correctly using python3. e.g. in print command.

Answer (score 0):

probably indent print(end=" ") after "else:"

Answer (score 0):

You should correctly align the lines of code below the statement else below:

```py
for row in range(7):
    for col in range(11):
        if ((col==0 or col==6 or col==10) or (row==3 and col==1))or((row==2) and (col==2 or col==8)) or (row==4 and col==2) or ((row==1) and (col==3 or col==7 or col==9)) or (row==5 and col==3) or ((row==0 or row==6) and (col==4)):
            print("*",end="")
else:
  print(end=" ")
  print()
```